# python 3 - having issues with strings of this type -> "ss:seconds:3\x01"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would figure the "\x01" as part of a string would be ignored but guess not.  How so I resolve so I print and use as intended? As a string

Thanks

```
key_hash = {}
key_hash["ss:seconds:3\x01"] = "topic-1"
key_hash["ss:seconds:3\x02"] = "topic-2"
key_hash["ss:seconds:3\x03"] = "topic-3"
key_hash["ss:seconds:3\x04"] = "topic-4"

for key,topic in key_hash.items():
    
    print(key,topic)
```

Here is the output:

```
ss:seconds:3 topic-1
ss:seconds:3 topic-2
ss:seconds:3 topic-3
ss:seconds:3 topic-4
```

But I want

```
ss:seconds:3\x01 topic-1
```

Comment: I don't see what the problem here is...

Answer (score 3):

They are not ignored, but your terminal displays all 4 control characters as zero-width glyphs. On my terminal (with the control characters in the output of `hexdump` emphasized):

```
$ python3 tmp.py
ss:seconds:3 topic-1
ss:seconds:3 topic-2
ss:seconds:3 topic-3
ss:seconds:3 topic-4
$ python3 tmp.py | hexdump -C
00000000  73 73 3a 73 65 63 6f 6e  64 73 3a 33 01 20 74 6f  |ss:seconds:3. to|
00000010  70 69 63 2d 31 0a 73 73  3a 73 65 63 6f 6e 64 73  |pic-1.ss:seconds|
00000020  3a 33 02 20 74 6f 70 69  63 2d 32 0a 73 73 3a 73  |:3. topic-2.ss:s|
00000030  65 63 6f 6e 64 73 3a 33  03 20 74 6f 70 69 63 2d  |econds:3. topic-|
00000040  33 0a 73 73 3a 73 65 63  6f 6e 64 73 3a 33 04 20  |3.ss:seconds:3. |
00000050  74 6f 70 69 63 2d 34 0a                           |topic-4.|
00000058
```

Comment: Emphasis inside a code block is far too subtle.

Comment: I had trouble earlier disabling the syntax highlighting; it looks a little better now. I added italics as well, but it's a shame there's no way to specify a different color.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you run into is that your text contains a hex-letter that is not printable: `\x01` is one letter (see f.e on [ascii-code.com](https://www.ascii-code.com/)).

You can see this when you check the strings lenght:

```
text = "ss:seconds:3\x01"

print('+' + text + '+')   # on my console: +ss:seconds:3+
print(text, len(text))   

1234567890123
ss:seconds:3* 13     # * is the non printable character \x01
```

You can (artificially) change the string to contain the hex representation for all non-printable characters like so:

```
from string import printable

def change_non_printables(text):
    p = set(printable)
    return ''.join((t if t in p else fr"\x{ord(t):02x}" for t in text))

modified = change_non_printables(text)
print(modified)
```

to output:

```
ss:seconds:3\x01
```

which you then could use as key in your dict.

Comment: You should change your format string so it outputs hex.

Comment: @Mark I tried using `fr"\x{ord(t):x}"` but that does not add 0 in front and I would have to do other shinanigans to make that happen so I opted for integer formatting of ord() value

Comment: Try `fr"\x{ord(t):02x}"`.  That hardly seems like shenanigans to me.

Comment: @Mark could have sworn I tried that - and the output for f.e. \x0e makes so much more sense now: ty.

Answer (score 0):

You could use raw string if I'm right.

```
key_hash = {}
key_hash[r"ss:seconds:3\x01"] = "topic-1"
key_hash[r"ss:seconds:3\x02"] = "topic-2"
key_hash[r"ss:seconds:3\x03"] = "topic-3"
key_hash[r"ss:seconds:3\x04"] = "topic-4"

for key,topic in key_hash.items():

    print(key,topic)
```

I got the output as

```
ss:seconds:3\x01 topic-1
ss:seconds:3\x02 topic-2
ss:seconds:3\x03 topic-3
ss:seconds:3\x04 topic-4
```